# How much time do I have after getting DeadlineExceededError?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to properly exit after catching DeadlineExceededError.  How much do I have left for cleaning up?

For example,

```
try:
  do_some_work()
except DeadlineExceededError:
  # How much more time do I have here?
  # Can clean_up() be as long as 1s, 5s, or longer?
  clean_up()
  return
more_work()
```

Comment: In my experience less than a second, I haven't seen a document ted figure, and you don't always get the grace period, which is dependent very much on why you get a DEE.

Answer (score 2):

If a request fails to return typically within 60 seconds for http requests, or 10 minutes for task queue requests and a `DeadlineExceededError` is thrown and not caught, the request is aborted and a 500 internal server error is returned. If the `DeadlineExceededError` is caught but a response is not produced quickly enough (**you have less than a second**), the request is aborted and a 500 internal server error is returned.

Well Documented Here : https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors

Once `DeadlineExceededError` is caught, You will get a time to add a task to perform `clean_up()` using `taskqueue` API

Answer (score 0):

Where is DeadlineExceededError coming from? I think the deadline is initialized somewhere, not a hardcoded value. If you [download the source code](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python) and look in google.appengine.api.apiproxy_rpc.py, you can take a look at the initializer.

```
class RPC(object):
"""Base class for implementing RPC of API proxy stubs.

To implement a RPC to make real asynchronous API call:
- Extend this class.
- Override _MakeCallImpl and/or _WaitImpl to do a real asynchronous call.
"""

IDLE = 0
RUNNING = 1
FINISHING = 2

def __init__(self, package=None, call=None, request=None, response=None,
           callback=None, deadline=None, stub=None):
"""Constructor for the RPC object.

All arguments are optional, and simply set members on the class.
These data members will be overriden by values passed to MakeCall.

Args:
  package: string, the package for the call
  call: string, the call within the package
  request: ProtocolMessage instance, appropriate for the arguments
  response: ProtocolMessage instance, appropriate for the response
  callback: callable, called when call is complete
  deadline: A double specifying the deadline for this call as the number of
            seconds from the current time. Ignored if non-positive.
  stub: APIProxyStub instance, used in default _WaitImpl to do real call
"""
self.__exception = None
self.__state = RPC.IDLE
self.__traceback = None

self.package = package
self.call = call
self.request = request
self.response = response
self.callback = callback
self.deadline = deadline
self.stub = stub
self.cpu_usage_mcycles = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the code, but I don't see anything specifically pointing out the grace period after DeadlineExceededError.